# Space used for all allocating the variable name

Tags: c, variables

Actually I just started learning C language.  I want to know where does the variable name get stored in the memory in C. Consider the following code:

```
int i = 10;
```

I'm not able to find where the name "`i`" is stored in memory.

Comment: The variable *name* isn't typically stored at all. It might be stored in debug symbols, but not in the live code. The only thing that needs storing is the variable itself.

Comment: Do you think there is any difference between variable and variable name?

Answer (score 8):

> I tried lot to know where does i stores in memory

In general, it's not stored anywhere in the executable's memory.

Before the program is linked ^, the string "`i`" is discarded and the object code (for this particular example) reduces to register accesses.

The compiler knows about `i` and keeps it distinct from the other registers in use for this code.

If you wanted to find some way to get access to this string, it could be through the debugging symbols which *are* stored with the program.  Unfortunately, getting access to this data is not for novices, and not particularly portable.

^ actually, this is only true if the code you showed is in local scope.  At file scope, the string `i` is preserved for linking and only then can it be discarded by the linker.

Here is an example of one the first intermediate outputs available from my compiler.  I took the liberty of putting your statement in local scope.  The lines which include `****` are comments which I had the compiler include so that it's easy to correlate the source with the assembly.  They are not used by the assembler (the next stage in the compile).  `i` has been replaced by an indirect access to `%rbp`.

```
   1:w.c           ****
   2:w.c           **** int main()
   3:w.c           **** {
   9                    .loc 1 3 0
  10                    .cfi_startproc
  11 0000 55            pushq   %rbp
  12                .LCFI0:
  13                    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
  14                    .cfi_offset 6, -16
  15 0001 4889E5        movq    %rsp, %rbp
  16                .LCFI1:
  17                    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
   4:w.c           ****     int i = 10;
  18                    .loc 1 4 0
  19 0004 C745FC0A      movl    $10, -4(%rbp)
  19      000000
   5:w.c           ****
   6:w.c           ****     return 0;
  20                    .loc 1 6 0
  21 000b B8000000      movl    $0, %eax
  21      00
   7:w.c           **** }
```

Later in the listing we can see the debug symbol for `i`.

```
  55 004e 5F000000      .long   0x5f
  56 0052 03            .uleb128 0x3
  57 0053 6900          .string "i"
  58 0055 01            .byte   0x1
  59 0056 04            .byte   0x4
  60 0057 5F000000      .long   0x5f
  61 005b 02            .byte   0x2
```

Answer (score 3):

The name doesn't even *exist* in your finished, compiled program. It's only a handy feature in your source code to make it readable by humans. You won't find variable names in the compiled binary anywhere — by that stage, they have been replaced by a complex, entangled web of pointers and numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where the line is written. If it's inside the function, then the variable will have auto storage. This means it will be stored on the stack, when the function is executing. And will not exist when the function exits.

If it's in "file-scope" it will have static storage. And will exist for the whole time the program is running.

Also, as Vlad pointed out. A variable may be optimized away if the compiler detects it is unused or has a constant value. In which case it will not occupy any space at all.

Note that I'm talking the variables themselves. The names aren't stored with the program. The native code doesn't need a variable name to access it, it needs only to know the region of memory it resides in.

Comment: IMHO it is also worth mentioning that variable may be «optimized out» entirely by the compiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, "bootnote" is an alias for "footnote"?

Comment: @BrianCain: Yeah, more or less.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, oh, I see, British English.  Jolly good.  ;)

Comment: Can't we all just get along?  ;)

Answer (score 1):

In native languages, variable names does not take any space.

Comment: Names don't, variables do.

Comment: @VladLazarenko:  OP, asks about where variable **name** stored in memory.  Did you read the question?

Comment: ...and you generally mean "low-level compiled languages". Not sure what "native" even means.